# Ubuntu Server not loading after grub

Tags: boot, grub2, ubuntu-server

I install Ubuntu Server 16.04 on a SATA3 - 750 GB, but I hadn't success in the first try. After booting with the USB, Grub2's console was loaded and I had to load manually the Ubuntu. (I also have another HD with Xubuntu installed)

To load the Ubuntu Server I did:

```
grub> set root=(hd1,msdos5)
grub> linux /install/vmlinuz
grub> initrd /install/initrd.gz
grub> boot
```

It worked and I was able to install the Ubuntu, but after select the option at grub I got frozen in a black screen with a similar message:

```
dev/sdb1: mount, files: XXXXXX, blocks XXXXXXX
```

What I have done to solve the problem:

- Check for consistency on the HD, no error found.
- When frozen in black scream, Ctrl+Alt+Del restart the system showing Ubuntu image before closing.
- I was able to load and use the OS in recovery mode.
- In recovery I execute all the options of update, check filesystem and others that work fine.
- The grub master was installed in my Xubuntu HD, so the config files for grub are saved there.

Some observations that I found when searching for solutions:

- I read that sdb1 can be the cause for not loading the OS.
- That I should specify the location of the root filesystem when loading the OS with grub, otherwise it could get kernel panic. The command should be:

  grub> linux /install/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1

I believe the problem is simple, the OS is not able to find the right file to start.

I need ideas to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

## UPDATE - update-grub command (output)

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (16.04) on /dev/sdb1
done
```

Comment: If you can boot Xubuntu then, with the external drive connected, open Terminal and do `sudo update-grub`. Hopefully it's all you need. It is not if you installed in a different mode, of course. BTW, UEFI or BIOS (Legacy)?

Comment: @MichaelBay, sorry for answering late, and thank you for the help. The command update-grub didn't work. I will update my question with the out come from the command. And about the different mode, UEFI or BIOS, I don't know what you mean. If you give an  explanation or something that I can check, I will answer that.

Comment: Almost any PC since almost a decade ago has UEFI, not BIOS. But also most of the UEFI PCs come with a compatibly mode ("BIOS"/Legacy/CSM) for older OSes that don't support UEFI. For installing an OS, and especially with dual or multi boot, not knowing about this modes and requirements is *not an option*. (...)

Comment: Apparently, in your case it's Legacy (or you're using an old BIOS PC). Now, `update-grub` seems to have found Ubuntu 16.04 so you should be able to select it in the initial Grub menu. Do you not see that menu -or- do you see it, select "Ubuntu 16.04" and it doesn't boot?

Comment: I see the Ubuntu in grub options, it doesn't properly load after selecting. I say properly, because when got stuck and using Ctrl+alt+del I can see a logo from ubuntu and the OS shunting down after.

Comment: A logo appearing in the server edition isn't normal. Or did you installed a desktop environment as well?

Comment: "Or did you installed a desktop environment as well?" - If I did that was not my intention. But what I can say is: I was able to enter in recovery mode and use the OS in console level only, not with interface.

Comment: I download Ubuntu server 18.04 and I will try it in live, then, if work, I will install it and remove the 16.04 version. Thanks for your help Michael! As lobO answered below, it doesn't seems easy to debug this problem.

Comment: Ubuntu Server IS "console only" (headless). It can have an "interface" if and only a DE is installed by the user. The default, again, is without it, command line only. And one more thing that can be very important for what to do next: (...)

Comment: **Anything you can do with Ubuntu Server can be done with Xubuntu.** So, perhaps you don't need a separated Ubuntu Server?

Comment: Good point. I didn't know that yet. I was installing more for knowledge and fun than for work or something like that. And because is a old desktop that I want to run as server.

Comment: Keep it simple. You already have a working Xubuntu. If you want to practice commands, open the Terminal, same thing. If you want to use server features install what's needed.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. After suffering from installing the Server, I will do that first! Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

This sort of issue is unfortunately very difficult to debug (even locally, but even more so across the web). In general you can try booting a live USB stick (as in, all the way to the OS, not just to the GRUB prompt) and checking which partition is marked as bootable. You'll then need to reconfigure GRUB to point to that partition. Once that's done booting should work.

Comment: Assuming Xubuntu (the one that boots) and Ubuntu Server were installed in the same, booting Xubuntu and running `update-grub` should be enough, shouldn't it?

Comment: After `update-grub` check whether your /boot/grub/grub.cfg contains the entries you expect. If it does then you should be golden. If not you may want to include it in the question.